# How to replace the specific range of characters in String only once

Tags: swift, string, replace

I'd like to achieve replacing of the starting two characters of the string, if they start with 00, to be + instead

Tried something like the following:

```
    if text.hasPrefix("00") {
        var string = text
        let offset = 1
        let index = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: offset)
        let range = index...index
        string.replaceSubrange(range, with: "+")
    }
```

but managing only to replace the 2nd character, what would be the most elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small function like this would make more sense,

```
func bySubstitutingZeros(number: String) -> String {
    if number.hasPrefix("00") {
        return "+" + number[number.index(number.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)...]
    }
    return number
}
```

Or you can as well create an extension on `String` class,

```
extension String {
    
    func byReplacingPrefix(_ prefix: String, with replacement: String) -> String {
        if self.hasPrefix(prefix) {
            return replacement + self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: prefix.count)...]
        }
        return self
    }
}

"0035850582919023".byReplacingPrefix("00", with: "+")
```

Output:

> +35850582919023

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
let range = index...index
```

That *is* the second character.

So just fix that range to start with the first character instead of the second character.

```
if text.hasPrefix("00") {
    var string = text
    let index = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
    let range = string.startIndex...index // ****
    string.replaceSubrange(range, with: "+")
}
```